# Dishwasher and sink drain smell

Tags: dishwasher

I have been trying to troubleshoot a smelly dishwasher for a few months now. Here is what I observed:

- Dishwasher does not smell normally
- Dishwasher smells almost immediately after a wash cycle starts
- Sink drain smells almost immediately after a wash cycle starts
- Dishwasher smells very bad after a wash cycle
- Plates smell bad after a wash cycle
- Dishwasher filter seems to need to be cleaned very often, about every week
- Dishwasher is about 3-4 years old. Do not remember this issue coming up until about six months ago. The dishwasher also broke and needed its pump replaced maybe a year or two ago.

Here is what I have fixed:

- Replaced drain hose (it was very dirty)
- Confirmed drain hose has proper high loop
- Used a wet vac to completely clean all accessible parts of inside and outside of dishwasher, including parts underneath it.
- Clean the dishwasher filter almost every time we wash
- Tried several cleaning solutions (baking soda, Affresh & other products)
- Really been careful to get all food chunks of any size off dishes
- Had an appliance repairman come check out the machine. He replaced the drain hose and did a very intense cleaning of the machine. He couldn't find any issues.

EDITS:

- Added picture under sink

[image: under sink]

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the undersink area showing the dishwasher hose, sink drain, trap, disposal (if you have one), etc.?

Comment: yeah, I also think this may be a plumbing problem.

Comment: Check the vent stack for blockage, which can cause sewer gas to back up into house from any drain.

Comment: Have you tried running a couple of empty loads with a cup of bleach?